# Inverse kinematics solutions pros and cons

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I know at least 3 different solutions to inverse kinematics problem. They are pseudo inverse jacobian, cyclic coordinate descent and ANFIS networks. I would like to know their advantages and disadvantages comparing to each other.

Comment: A fourth method is to calculate closed-form solutions and just program those equations in.   This is the method I always use unless I have a very unusual robot for which I cannot compute the equations.   This has happened once in thirty years (for a robot with a nonspherical wrist).   Since then, closed form solutions for even those robots have been published.

Comment: maybe off topic, but this is nice: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~junggon/tools/gear.html